# geoFirestore - add new document with array as one of the document data property

Tags: database, typescript, firebase, geofirestore

While i try to add new document to the DB with geoFirestore and try to set one of the property as array with DocumentReference (refers to a document location in a Firestore database) i get the following error:

FirebaseError: Function `DocumentReference.set()` called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom object

If i set there an empty array its success.
BTW if i set there a string or number its work too

**The inseration code:**

```
await geocollection.add({
                        coordinates: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(latlng.lat, latlng.lng),
                        arrayOfRef: [newRef]
                     });
```

I try to use `Object.asset()` to the `newRef` but get the same result.

Thanks for the helpers.

Answer (score 0):

So in a lot of cases `geofirestore` minimally modifies the doc you give and then passes it through to Firestore. In this case it looks like Firebase/Firestore is throwing the error, not `geofirestore`.

I suspect that the issue is with the reference you're using. If that reference is provided by `geofirestore`, it's not necessarily a `DocumentReference` that Firestore uses, it is a [`GeoDocumentReference`](https://geofirestore.com/classes/_geodocumentreference_.geodocumentreference.html). You'll likely want to get the actual `DocumentReference` from the [`native` property](https://geofirestore.com/classes/_geodocumentreference_.geodocumentreference.html#native):

```js
await geocollection.add({
  coordinates: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(latlng.lat, latlng.lng),
  arrayOfRef: [newRef.native]
});
```

Let me know if that helps! I'm also making a few assumptions as to your code, so seeing more of what happens before you call the `add` method would be awesome.

Comment: hi michael, thanks but its not the scenario, i set newRef as a DocumentReference. 
i saw a suggestion to use Object.assign() but still not work.

Comment: Can I see more of the code, like everything leading up to the `geocollection.add`?

Comment: as you can see, the newRef is returning from insertNewRef which using firestore-admin to insert new document and return the `DocumentReference` of it: 
`await GeoLocationDB.get().then(async function(querySnapshot){
   await insertNewRef().then(async function(newRef){
     if (querySnapshot.size == 0){
     await geocollection.add({
       coordinates: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(latlng.lat, latlng.lng),
       posts: [newRef]
     });`

Comment: Ok, so I attempted to implement something you're doing in a StackBlitz (I'm using the web client, not the server).

Here's the blitz, and it seems to work just fine. However I noticed an issue with Firestore where if the coordinates are [0, 0] it throws an issue (I'm gonna pass this issue to the Firebase team)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/geofirestore-169?file=index.ts